# Iterate over vector<vector<?> > with for_each

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm having some trouble iterating over a `vector<vector<?> >` with the [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) function. 
Whenever I do something like this (where `matrix` is my nested vector):

```
int size = 0;    
for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [](vector<int> &vec) {
    size += vec.size();
});
```

Then the compiler complains at me with a `expected primary-expression before '[' token` error (there are more that are the same error but with the `]` and `&` characters). What am I doing wrong? The example at cppreference over [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) has similar syntax with an `int`, so what makes this different?

Comment: What is ```size```?And how you are passing to that lambda function?

Comment: What compiler, and what flags?  You probably don't have C++11 enabled.  Second, you need a `&` inside the `[]`s to access `size`.

Comment: `size` is just initialized to 0 just outside the loop. Sorry about that; thought it would be implied. I'm actually not sure which compiler it is, but I'm just doing the standard `g++` command.

Comment: ```g++``` is ```gcc``` compiler! :p

Comment: try `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: note that you can go `for (auto&& m : matrix ) size += m.size();`, and for the extra case, before that `for (auto&& matrix: bla)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're including the right header, `using namespace std;` (I prefer to explicitly prefix with `std::` as below), and enabling C++11 for your compiler?  You'll need to capture `size` too.  Anyway - working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = { { 1, 2 }, {3, 4, 5}, {6} };
    size_t size = 0;
    std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [&size](std::vector<int> &vec) {
        size += vec.size();
    });
    std::cout << size << '\n';
}
```

See it run [here](http://ideone.com/Vt2E1g)

---

Regarding your question in a comment:

> What if this is surrounded by another for_each loop that's getting each vector individually; what would that look like?

You can have nested `for_each` loops as follows, but it might not be what you need functionally - no way to tell from such a vague question:

```
    std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),
        [&size, &matrix](std::vector<int>& outer_vec)
        {
            std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),
                [&size](std::vector<int> &vec)
                {
                    size += vec.size();
                });
        });
```

Comment: So what goes in the brackets is whatever piece of data I'm extracting? What is the purpose of them? What if this is surrounded by another `for_each` loop that's getting each vector individually; what would that look like?

Comment: The brackets list the variables from the enclosing scope that you'd like to either copy or keep references to, for use at the time the lambda is invoked.  The special notation `[&]` can be used to automatically capture references to whatever variables are used, while `[=]` creates copies of them.  For further details, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Well, now I get a new error: `error: 'vec' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @T145: *"now I get a new error:"* - the code is valid, I posted a link to ideone.com where it's running.  If you have an error then you've mis-copied it or have an issue with your compiler (the likely issue is that you're not specifying `-std=c++11` on the command line).  Without seeing the exact code you're trying to compile, I can offer no further advice.  Separately, I've addressed your question about nested loops in my answer.